# Add a dynamic dropdown field to Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamicform

I am building a form based on the model with this structure

```
public class DynamicFormElementsModel
{
    //param might be shown in UI , but will not pass while setting params for report . Example select org.  
    public bool ReportParameter { get; set; }

    public string  ParamName { get; set; }

    public string ParamLabel { get; set; }

    public string ParamType { get; set; }

    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public string ParamValue { get; set;}
}
```

And in Razor i am building the control like

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => Model.ReportId)
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Parameters.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">@Model.Parameters[i].ParamLabel</label>

                    @switch (@Model.Parameters[i].ParamType.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "textbox":
                            if (@Model.Parameters[i].Visible)
                            {
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Parameters[i].ParamValue" name="@Model.Parameters[i].ParamName" />
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Parameters[i].ParamValue" name="@Model.Parameters[i].ParamName" />
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                </div>
            }
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        }
```

Normal textboxes will be rendered correctly with this approach . But how can i make a dropdown and  fill the dropdown  from a table id , name value pair from the sql table

Comment: For a start your model should have a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for the options

Comment: how can i map that with dynamic form element

Comment: Something like `case "select": @Html.DropDownList(Model.Parameters[i].ParamName, Model.Parameters[i].YouSelectListProperty)`

Comment: i am struggling to get the values in post action as i am getting NULL while pOST . Is it because of html tags i used?

Comment: You have not shown your POST method :) - and you will also need to show the main model that you use in the view (your name attributes are not based on that so will not bind - in fact they do not even have collection indexers to bind to a collection)